# Allegro in Ubuntu: undefined reference to `al_install_system'

Tags: c++, g++, ubuntu-10.04, allegro5

I tried installing the Allegro library today. I have same experience in C++, but it seems I have none in doing stuff like that. I have compiled Allegro 5.0 from source and put it in /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/include/allegro5. But when I try to compile my code, this comes up:

```
    > g++ test2.cc -o test2
/home/chris/Desktop/c++/test2/.objs/main.o||In function `main':|
main.cpp:(.text+0x22)||undefined reference to `al_install_system'|
main.cpp:(.text+0x3e)||undefined reference to `al_create_display'|
main.cpp:(.text+0x6b)||undefined reference to `al_map_rgb'|
main.cpp:(.text+0x8e)||undefined reference to `al_clear_to_color'|
main.cpp:(.text+0x93)||undefined reference to `al_flip_display'|
main.cpp:(.text+0xa1)||undefined reference to `al_rest'|
main.cpp:(.text+0xa9)||undefined reference to `al_destroy_display'|
||=== Build finished: 7 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

The code I am using:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

   if(!al_init()) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   display = al_create_display(640, 480);
   if(!display) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
   al_flip_display();
   al_rest(10.0);
   al_destroy_display(display);
   return 0;
}
```

`allegro-config --libs` returns nothing. I had Allegro as package first, but it didn'T work either.

Comment: /usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/include/allegro5 is not the right place to put library's include files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling C++ code with allegro 5 and g++.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377204/compiling-c-code-with-allegro-5-and-g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link with the Allegro libraries, but you don't seem to do so.

> `allegro-config --libs` returns nothing.

There's part of your problem. Normally, you should be able to add it to your command line, like so:

```
g++ `allegro-config --libs` test2.cc -o test2
```

On my system (Ubuntu 10.10) it gives this:

```
$ allegro-config --libs
-L/usr/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lalleg-4.2.2
```

Are you invoking the right `allegro-config`? Maybe you should specify the full path to it?

Comment: As I said, I haven't installed Allegro by packages, but rather compiled it from source. When I had the package installed, it returned what you posted above. Should I try deleting Allegro5 and installing the packages again or would that change nothing?

Comment: I repeat the two questions above.

Comment: With nothing I meant it's not installed, sorry if that was unclear. I tried reinstalling the packages (liballegro-4.2, liballegro-4.2-dev). The command now outputs the same as on your Ubuntu, and invoking the right still leads to the same output as in the OP.

Comment: The Ubuntu packages give you Allegro 4, which should not even let you compile the code from the OP, let alone link it. Either way, you could also manually add `-L/path/to/your/allegro/libs -lalleg` or something like that.

Comment: Oh, haha, seems like I'm stupid :I An Allegro 4 code works fine - if  Allegro 5 doesn't work yet, I'll just start with this first. Thanks for coping with my stupidity :p

Comment: @Suyo, Allegro 5 works fine. Note that it is a complete rewrite from version 4, and the build process is different as well.

Comment: I think the real answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377204/compiling-c-code-with-allegro-5-and-g/6377275#6377275

Answer (score 21):

Allegro 5 uses pkg-config.

```
gcc foo.c -o foo $(pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0)
```

You will also need to specify addon libraries that you use:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo $(pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_image-5.0)
```

Comment: After running 'pkg-config --list-all | grep allegro', I realized that I had to omit the dot zero for the command to work for me: 'gcc allegro_play.c  -o play $(pkg-config --libs allegro-5)'