# Compiling C++ code with allegro 5 and g++

Tags: c++, g++, allegro, allegro5

What flags do I need to add to g++ in order to compile code using allegro 5? I tried

```
g++ allegro5test.cpp -o allegro5test `allegro-config --libs`
```

but that is not working. I'm using ubuntu 11.04. I installed allegro 5 using the instructions at http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_SVN/Linux/Debian

I tried:

```
g++ allegro5test.cpp -o allegro5test `allegro-config --cflags --libs`
```

And it also gives a bunch of undefined errors, like: undefined reference to `al_install_system'

`allegro-config --cflags --libs` outputs:

```
-I/usr/local/include
-L/usr/local/lib -lalleg
```

Comment: Does `allegro5test.cpp` have the line `#include <allegro5/allegro.h>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allegro in Ubuntu: undefined reference to `al_install_system'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221981/allegro-in-ubuntu-undefined-reference-to-al-install-system)

Comment: It's not a duplicate because that answer didn't solved the problem. That OP gave up and used a previous version of the library instead, and marked the answer as accepted because he is a nice person. This thread has the real answer.

Comment: The OP in that question marked the wrong answer. The answer I gave was correct. Allegro 5 uses pkg-config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you successfully installed **allegro5** on your system from the SVN. One thing you should know is that this build doesn't come with **allegro-config**. If you have it on your system it means you have previously installed **allegro4**.

allegro5 brings many changes, including different initialization procedures, library and function names.

Here's a hello world application for new version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

   if(!al_init()) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   display = al_create_display(640, 480);
   if(!display) {
      fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
      return -1;
   }

   al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
   al_flip_display();
   al_rest(10.0);
   al_destroy_display(display);
   return 0;
}
```

**Notice** how the command to compile this application refers to another include directory and library names, which are different from the previous version of allegro:

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello -I/usr/include/allegro5 -L/usr/lib -lallegro
```

Comment: The code formatting uses the ` character, so it didn't show up in the question, I reformatted it to fix it.

Comment: @Jcubed I would tend to agree that you need to specify `--cflags` too.

Comment: Its giving a bunch of undefined errors, like: undefined reference to `al_install_system'

Comment: @Jcubed Please edit your original question with this information rather than leaving it as a comment.

Comment: Well, I am using allegro 5, so that command is not working for me. I was able to compile allegro 4.2 code fine, but thats not what I need help with.

Comment: More important than that, the tutorial you used forgot to state that you need to execute `make install` as superuser (root), or the libraries/headers won't be installed on your system.

Answer (score 3):

Allegro 5 uses pkg-config.

```
pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_image-5.0
```

And so on for each library you are using.