# How do I link Allegro 5 from my Makefile?

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, allegro5

I need to link the Allegro Game Development Library from my **Makefile**. When I do this, the compiler returns:

```
Undefinied Reference < Function Name >.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before trying to embed the compilation line into the Makefile, make sure you understand how to do it the command line, and more important, make sure it works:

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello -I/usr/include/allegro5 -L/usr/lib -lallegro
```

Then, a simple `Makefile` to compile [`hello.cpp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377204/compiling-c-code-with-allegro-5-and-g/6377275#6377275) could be:

```
CXX=g++
CFLAGS=
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib -lallegro
INCLUDE=-I. -I/usr/include/allegro5

OBJS=hello.o
OUT=hello

all: hello_rule

clean:
        rm -rf *.o hello

hello_rule: $(OBJS)
        $(CXX) $(OBJS) -o $(OUT) $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: For Windows, you would have to execute: `gcc src/main.c -o hello -I/include -L/lib -lallegro-5.0.3-md`

Comment: Or you can link against liballegro-5.0.3-monolith-md, which is the same as linking against Allegro and all of its addons.