# How should I link libraries in automake normally linked with pkg-config?

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake, allegro5

I'm trying to get my project buildable with automake. Specifically while using Allegro5.

I can build my code using the following command just fine

```
g++ -std=c++0x *.cpp -o mygame $(pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0 \
allegro_acodec-5.0 allegro_audio-5.0 allegro_color-5.0 allegro_dialog-5.0 \
allegro_font-5.0 allegro_image-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 allegro_memfile-5.0 \
allegro_physfs-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0)
```

But my Makefile will not work.

Here is my src/Makefile.am

```
bin_PROGRAMS = mygame

AM_CXXFLAGS = "-std=c++0x"

mygame_SOURCES = Animation.cpp Body.cpp GameObject.cpp Menu.cpp Vector3.cpp \
    Arena.cpp Button.cpp Keyboard.cpp Mesh.cpp Assets.cpp Character.cpp \
    main.cpp Mouse.cpp Barrier.cpp Environment.cpp Manager.cpp TitleMenu.cpp

mygame_LDADD = allegro-5.0 allegro_acodec-5.0 allegro_audio-5.0 \
    allegro_color-5.0 allegro_dialog-5.0 allegro_font-5.0 allegro_image-5.0 \
    allegro_main-5.0 allegro_memfile-5.0 allegro_physfs-5.0 \
    allegro_primitives-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0

CLEANFILES = mygame *.o
```

And here is my configure.ac

```
AC_INIT(bayou, 0.1.0)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE

AC_LANG_CPLUSPLUS
AC_PROG_CXX
LT_INIT

AC_OUTPUT(
    Makefile \
    src/Makefile\
)
```

Running my first command works just fine. Running make gives me

```
make: *** No rule to make target `allegro-5.0', needed by 'mygame'.  Stop.
```

So how should I set up my configure.ac and Makefile.am's so I can use libraries I normally link with pkg-config?

Comment: I think I found out how to set up the command using -L and -lallegro. I will need to run `pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0 allegro_acodec-5.0 allegro_audio-5.0 allegro_color-5.0 llegro_dialog-5.0 allegro_font-5.0 allegro_image-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 allegro_memfile-5.0 allegro_physfs-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0` to get a list of the libraries, then I will follow this question's answer. I will have to do that when I arrive home from work though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560760/how-do-i-link-allegro-5-from-my-makefile

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My lead in the suggestion worked. I did not have to modify my configure.ac (though I probably should so I can verify expected packages are installed)

Anyway, I ran `pkg-config <insert libs from comment here>` in a terminal window, which gave the following output

```
-L/usr/local/lib -lallegro_acodec -lallegro_audio -lallegro_color 
-lallegro_dialog -lallegro_image -lallegro_main -lallegro_memfile 
-lallegro_physfs -lallegro_primitives -lallegro_ttf -lallegro_font
-lallegro
```

So my new Makefile.am looks like

```
bin_PROGRAMS = mygame

AM_CXXFLAGS = "-std=c++0x"

mygame_SOURCES = Animation.cpp Body.cpp GameObject.cpp Menu.cpp Vector3.cpp \
    Arena.cpp Button.cpp Keyboard.cpp Mesh.cpp Assets.cpp Character.cpp \
    main.cpp Mouse.cpp Barrier.cpp Environment.cpp Manager.cpp TitleMenu.cpp

mygame_LDADD = -Lusr/local/lib -lallegro_acodec \
    -lallegro_audio -lallegro_color -lallegro_dialog -lallegro_image \
    -lallegro_main -lallegro_memfile -lallegro_physfs -lallegro_primitives \
    -lallegro_ttf -lallegro_font -lallegro

CLEANFILES = mygame *.o
```

I'd like to thank the academy and my parents for seeing me through this trying time. They've meant so much to me! *blows kisses

Answer (score 1):

`pkg-config` is there to tell you dynamically which paths/flags to use.
It is meant to be used *dynamically*, rather than to run it on your development machine and then copy'n'paste it into the makefile and then expect it to run on any deployment machine.

Here's an updated `Makefile.am`, based on your own answer:

```
bin_PROGRAMS = mygame
AM_CXXFLAGS = "-std=c++0x"

PKGLIBS=allegro-5.0 \
    allegro_acodec-5.0 allegro_audio-5.0 allegro_color-5.0 allegro_dialog-5.0 \
    allegro_font-5.0 allegro_image-5.0 allegro_main-5.0 allegro_memfile-5.0 \
    allegro_physfs-5.0 allegro_primitives-5.0 allegro_ttf-5.0
mygame_CXXFLAGS = $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(PKGLIBS)) $(AM_CXXFLAGS)
mygame_LDADD = $(shell pkg-config --libs $(PKGLIBS))


mygame_SOURCES = Animation.cpp Body.cpp GameObject.cpp Menu.cpp Vector3.cpp \
    Arena.cpp Button.cpp Keyboard.cpp Mesh.cpp Assets.cpp Character.cpp \
    main.cpp Mouse.cpp Barrier.cpp Environment.cpp Manager.cpp TitleMenu.cpp
```

it might be that in your setup, the entire allegro-foo doesn't need any special compiler-flags, but it might as well need some. therefore my example also sets the compiler-flags for your program (`mygame_CXXFLAGS`).
finally, it get's rid of the unneeded `CLEANFILES`.

Also, you could go the autotools route, and use the [`PKG_CHECK_MODULES`](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html) macro in your `configure.ac`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try it out when I get home from work.