# Allegro - 'pkg-config' doesn't work

Tags: c++, codeblocks, undefined-reference, allegro5, tdm-mingw

I have problem compiling code from https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Allegro_5_Tutorial/Displays on CodeBlocks:

```
#define ALLEGRO_STATICLINK
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = NULL;

if(!al_init())
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to initialize allegro!\n");
    return -1;
}

display = al_create_display(640, 480);
if(!display)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "failed to create display!\n");
    return -1;
}

al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));

al_flip_display();

al_rest(10.0);

al_destroy_display(display);

return 0;
}
```

Compiler gives error "undefined reference" for each "al_" function.
I found "solution" ([Allegro in Ubuntu: undefined reference to `al_install_system'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221981/allegro-in-ubuntu-undefined-reference-to-al-install-system) & [Compiling C++ code with allegro 5 and g++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377204/compiling-c-code-with-allegro-5-and-g)), but now compiler gives error `g++.exe: error: 'pkg-config: No such file or directory`.
How can I fix that?

//EDIT: CodeBlocks generated build command:
`g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Obvi.exe obj\Debug\Main.o  'pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0.10'  ..\..\libs\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.1-tdm\lib\liballegro-5.0.10-static-mt.a ..\..\libs\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.1-tdm\lib\libvorbisfile-1.3.2-static-mt.a ..\..\libs\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.1-tdm\lib\libvorbis-1.3.2-static-mt.a ..\..\libs\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.1-tdm\lib\libdumb-0.9.3-static-mt.a ..\..\libs\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.1-tdm\lib\libFLAC-1.2.1-static-mt.a ..\..\libs\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.1-tdm\lib\libfreetype-2.4.8-static-mt.a ..\..\libs\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.1-tdm\lib\libogg-1.2.1-static-mt.a ..\..\libs\allegro-5.0.10-mingw-4.7.1-tdm\lib\libzlib-1.2.5-static-mt.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdiplus.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libpsapi.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libopengl32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libglu32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomdlg32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a ..\..\..\TDM-GCC-64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a`

Comment: can you show the command you're running to compile?

Comment: @murphyslaw command added

Comment: when you open the terminal can you do `pkg-config` ? If not adding the path to `pkg-config` to your environment variables should fix that.

Comment: `pkg-config` does not come with mingw. I think it does not even come with cygwin. You can compile and use `pkg-config` on windows but it is not a good idea. You should use -I and -L compilation options to tell the compiler where your include files and libraries are.Also, http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/ shows how can you use external libraries in your code

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia the problem is that when I use `-Lallegro-5.0.10-monolith-static-mt` I don't get any errors (it seems to find it), but I still get error later:     `D:/C++Dev/workspace/Obvi/Main.cpp:10: undefined reference to     `al_install_system'`