# Compiling Allegro 5.0 libs on ubuntu: "undefined reference to ..."

Tags: allegro, allegro5

I'm new to Allegro, Ubuntu, and C++ ... sorry in advance...

I just installed Allegro 4. Something from the ubuntu software manager. I then followed the directions [of this page](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_SVN/Linux/Debian) to install Allegro 5. I don't think my libs are linked correctly, but I don't exactly know how to manually change that.

My code:

```
#include <allegro.h> //the allegro 4 header?
#include <allegro/allegro5.h> //the allegro 5 header?

int main(){
    allegro_init();
}

END_OF_MAIN()
```

My compile line:

```
g++ allegro_test.cpp -o output.out `pkg-config --libs allegro5.0`
```

My output:

```
allegro_test.cpp (.text+0x2a) undefined refrence to '_install_allegro_check_version'
```

I assume it is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221981/allegro-in-ubuntu-undefined-reference-to-al-install-system), but I cannot figure out how to get the library linked. I'd like to have it know automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question you linked:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo $(pkg-config --libs allegro-5.0)
```

However, the source code you've posted is Allegro 4. Allegro 5 is not backward compatible. The A5 equivalent is:

```
#include <allegro/allegro5.h>

int main() {
   al_init();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That seems to have been it... the rest of my commented out code to initialize the keyboard and such needs to be updated now too.     Thanks!!!!

Comment: The manual @ http://allegro.cc/manual/5/ should be helpful. It also has inline links to any examples that use the particular function on that page.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late to answer this, but there might be someone somewhere seeking for an answer.

the header file is wrong; it should be like this:-

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
```