# Make IDE-wide configuration changes in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, compilation, settings, compiler-flags

I have been working on some GUI-related projects in Eclipse CDT. They always require me a specific command line pattern (Project > GCC C Linker) in order to load the libraries properly:

[image: The menu itself]

I can't manage to keep that configuration for every project I start. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO it is not possible. See in `Windows > Preferences > C/C++ Build > Setttings` these options were not provided.

So all these options are specific to a project. Means you can have different options for different projects.

Comment: No scripts / source code mods in order to get a similar result?

Comment: No. You have to write your own plugin for this.